Number of distinct minimal rectangles of a certain polyomino
Taking some polyomino and rotating and translating its copies, we can tile a rectangle. For example, two L-trominoes can make a rectangle in the following manner:

the minimal rectangle is the rectangle obtained by the least number of copies. For example, the above rectangle is minimal, as no rectangle can be obtained by using only one tromino, while a rectangle obtained by several copies of the above rectangle wouldn't be minimal.
For some polyominoes, the minimal rectangle is unique. For others, like these hexominoes, there are two distinct minimal rectangles:

One can obtain similar constructions yielding two distinct minimal rectangles by using staircase-like polyominoes like the above hexominoes.
I've struggles to find a polyomino which has three or more minimal rectangles. So my question is: For which $n$ does there exist a polyomino which yields $n$ distinct minimal rectangles?
My guess is that $n$ minimal rectangles exist only for $n=1,2$, which would be rather boring. Hopefully someone can prove (or disprove) this :)

Edit:
Looking at the results at polyominoes.org, the minimal rectangles for small polyminoes are all formed by an even number of copies (they have even order), although they allow for reflections as well, whereas this is disallowed in the question. Results from the site agree with the hypothesis that $n\ge 3$ is impossible.

$n = 0$ is also a possibility, since there are polyominos which cannot be made to form a rectangle at all.

But if no rectangles exist, then the term minimal makes no sense, as the set of rectangles is empty!
